# ADB stopping at <waiting for devices>

Tags: android, performance, adb, fastboot

I was trying to install some custom recovery and ROM on to my phone when I got to this situation.

**(I have my windows update turned off)**

ADB or fastboot shows

```
<waiting for devices>
```

I tried and saw few solutions.
I'm writing a detailed solution to this.
this was how I solved it.
if you have more suggestions you can answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the only reason for this is that your PC is not recognizing Phone.which is a driver problem.

You have to understand a few things before starting with the solution.
you may know this too.

- when you are in your recovery adb gets into something like recovery mode(just framing some terms myself)
- in bootloader, it takes fastload mode.

each of this mode needs different drivers other than what the driver you use with adb when your phone is running on OS.

so what you have to do is.

if you are trying to get into recovery mode or fastload mode.

- open device manager(settings>devices>(more options)Device manager).
- now boot the phone into the required mode using manual or adb method.
- the device manager reloads and a new driver will be shown. either in Android or pointing device or others folder.
- ***select the driver and update online.***(always preferred).
- if you don't find an online driver you have to select manual update here.
  [image]
  select browse my computer.
  [image]
  select let me pick.
  [image]
  select browse.

at last, you have to select the usb-driver provided by the google.
in 
`sdk>extras>google>usb-driver`

it will show the updatable driver.select and press next to install.
press ok now it should work correctly.

Comment: Where to download the usb driver?

Comment: I can't to find the usb-driver folder

Comment: Oh, I solved! You can download usb-driver here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: This worked for me (thank you). On newer updates of Windows 10 you have to go to Windows update and let it check for updates, then scroll down to the drivers you need.

Answer (score 16):

Happened to MACOS Mojave 10.14.6 while trying to install twrp-3.3.1-2-enchilada.img.

Solved it by running:

> adb reboot-bootloader

Then, when the phone boot into bootloader,

```
fastboot boot twrp-3.3.1-2-enchilada.img
```

worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

Run following command to get your device into FastBoot mode (from adb-driver folder if using Windows System)

```
adb reboot-fastboot
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've just spent a lot of time with the same problem, and it turns out to be because I have a Samsung phone.

There are a log of Fastboot blogs out there but what they don't always mention is, Samsung devices have no fastboot mode. So if yours is a Samsung device, don't waste time on any of the drivers and settings, because it will not work on Samsung. You can use adb but not fastboot.

There's another post with more info here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187573/111755.

Comment: what about if I am using a Samsung phone to deploy an app to my phone? I'm trying to use the WSL (Ubuntu) but it can't ever recognize my phone outright. It's present in my device manager, but I still get the "waiting for any device" message when I run the WSL shell in cmd.

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging in the phone settings?

Comment: I did. No difference.

Comment: So @ErickAdam did you follow the steps for Ubuntu? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device says, "Ubuntu Linux: There are two things that need to be set up correctly: each user that wants to use adb needs to be in the plugdev group, and the system needs to have udev rules installed that cover the device." But actually if you are trying to use USB under WSL,. it may not supported; see here for info and a project aiming to make it possible https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/

Comment: I actually figured it out. I was able to make the adb in Ubuntu WSL (/usr/bin/adb) equal to the adb in my Windows (/platform-tools/adb). I tried doing it before and had trouble, but finally figured it out, so now I can connect through USB.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was not turning on `usb debugging`.

(settings -> developer options(you should activate this if you don't see this option) -> usb debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I couldn't even see my Android device in Windows 10 Device Manager until I went into Settings/General/Developer options and set Select USB Configuration to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) instead of the default Charging Only, and also found a different USB cable that wasn't a charging-only one. Then, as @sushanthkille indicated above, I still had to install an updated driver, but the way he describes via Device Manager didn't work. For my LG G4, I had to go to https://www.lg.com/us/lgeai/Drivers/pages/mobile-drivers.html (found via googling for windows 10 LG G4 drivers) download the Windows driver, and install it manually. After all that, my G4 finally showed up in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update Windows 10 to resolve this issue.

I believe the needed update was a driver update for Android Bootloader Interface from Google, Inc. Windows updated several things at once so I can't verify that is what specifically solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's the drivers' issue on Windows!

Just install the appropriate OEM driver from here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

1. download the Google USB Driver from the official website (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)
2. Turn **off your device** and connect with your PC or laptop with a USB plugging
3. go to the device manager, You will see **Other devices**. There you will see the **Android option**. Right-click on it and press on **update driver**, then click on Brouse my computer for driver S/W. then Let me pick from the list and continue with All devices and next. Then browse again and select the file from the folder you have downloaded and click on **install**. and **restart**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was detected by adb but not fastboot, and it was solved just disconnecting the cable and reconnecting it again, so the phone is properly detected.

That is, although it was detected by adb (`adb devices`), when i instructed it to reboot in fastboot (`adb reboot bootloader`), it did not recognize the device straight away. Reconnecting allowed it to realize the change in state, and now it was properly recognized (`fastboot devices`) and it would follow any instruction properly.